# Proguard does not support Java 8?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

When i try to use proguard on my application it prints out this error. :

```
C:\Users\ahmooza\Desktop\proguard4.11\lib>"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/bin/ja
va.exe" -jar proguard @myconfig.pro
Error: Unable to access jarfile proguard

C:\Users\ahmooza\Desktop\proguard4.11\lib>"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/bin/ja
va.exe" -jar proguard.jar @myconfig.pro
ProGuard, version 4.11
Reading program jar [C:\Users\ahmooza\Desktop\proguard4.11\lib\Monitor.jar]
Error: Can't read [C:\Users\ahmooza\Desktop\proguard4.11\lib\Monitor.jar] (Can't
process class [org/Shed/Common/Counter$1.class] (Unsupported class version numb
er [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)))
```

So i reverted all code that uses java 8 and now no code uses java 8 and i still get this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ProGuard version 5.0 supports Java 8. At this time of writing, it is in beta. You can download it from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard%20beta/5.0beta/).

Answer (score 1):

Try java compiler setting, src=1.7 target = 1.7
Proguard works on processing the byte code.
You have to avoid all java1.8 features.

Comment: how do i do that? on the cmd?

Comment: either on the cmd, or better in eclipse (or other development env) at java compiler settings.

Comment: in ant : compiler option "target=1.7"